# How do i access the value in an object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

`When I try to print out the response from the snapshot, I get an instance of an object.

[image: Shows a future builder and a future property using a provider]

[image: instance of Deposit]

How do I access the value inside the object?

This is the sample code in the deposit

```
class Deposit {
  String id;
  String merchantId;
  String accountId;
  int amount;
  bool ismarkedasPaid;
  String paidAt;
  String completedAt;
  String status;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  Deposit(
      {this.accountId,
      this.merchantId,
      this.amount,
      this.completedAt,
      this.createdAt,
      this.ismarkedasPaid,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.paidAt,
      this.status,
      this.id});

  factory Deposit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Deposit(
      id: json['id'],
      merchantId: json['merchant_id'],
      accountId: json['account_id'],
      amount: json['amount'],
      ismarkedasPaid: json['is_marked_as_paid'],
      paidAt: json['paid_at'],
      completedAt: json['completed_at'],
      status: json['completed'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to copy a small reproducible code instead of links to some screenshots

Comment: You should include the code contains your `Deposit` model as well

Comment: I just added the code of what the deposit contains

Answer (score 0):

Use `snapshot.data.xxx`

The `xxx` represent the value inside the object.

Since you have assign snapshot.data to transaction, you may get the object value by calling `transaction.xxx`.